# Is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{\int_\delta^ \frac{\pi}{2} \cos^n (x )dx}{\int_0^ \frac{\pi}{2} \cos^n (x )dx}= 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I was trying to solve this problem:

> Suppose $f$ is a Riemann integrable function and $|f(t) − f(0)| \le M t$ for some positive constant $M$ on $[0,\frac \pi 2]$. It follows that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x)\cos^n (x )dx}{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^n (x )dx} =f(0)$$

and I tried to use squeeze theorem

> Since $\cos(x)$ is monotone decreasing on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ then for all $\varepsilon >0 \ \exists  \delta >0, \ N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that   for all $\delta<x< \frac{\pi}{2},$ $\cos^n (x )<\varepsilon \ \forall n \ge N$
> $$\frac{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x)\cos^n (x )dx}{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^n (x )dx}= \frac{\int_0^\delta  f(x)\cos^n (x )dx +\int_\delta^ \frac{\pi}{2}  f(x)\cos^n (x )dx }{\int_0^\delta  \cos^n (x )dx +\int_\delta^ \frac{\pi}{2}  \cos^n (x )dx} $$$$\frac{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x)\cos^n (x )dx}{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^n (x )dx} \le (f(0)+M \delta ) + \frac{M\pi}{2}\cdot \frac{\int_\delta^ \frac{\pi}{2}  \cos^n (x )dx}{\int_0^ \frac{\pi}{2}  \cos^n (x )dx}$$

The last part $\frac{\int_\delta^ \frac{\pi}{2}  \cos^n (x )dx}{\int_0^ \frac{\pi}{2}  \cos^n (x )dx}$ should tend to  $0$ but I couldn't prove or disprove that.

Answer (score 1):

It just needs some inequality techniques
$$ \cos^n(1)(1-\delta) \leq \int_{\delta}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n(x)\leq \frac{\pi}{2}\cos^n(\delta)\quad \int_{0}^{\delta}\cos^n(x)\geq \frac{\delta}{2}\cos^n (\frac{\delta}{2})$$

$$\frac{\int_{\delta}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n(x)}{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n(x)} \leq \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}\cos^n(\delta)}{\cos^n(1)(1-\delta)+\frac{\delta}{2}\cos^n (\frac{\delta}{2})}=\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}(\frac{\cos(\delta)}{\cos(\frac{\delta}{2})})^n}{(1-\delta)(\frac{\cos(1)}{\cos(\frac{\delta}{2})})^n+\frac{\delta}{2}} \longrightarrow  0\quad \text{as}\quad n\to \infty
$$

Comment: The inequality $\int_{0}^{\delta}\cos^n(x)dx\geq \frac{\delta}{2}$ is wrong: by DCT the LHS goes to zero with $n$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, i did some revision

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $\int_0^{\delta}\cos^n(x)\geq\int_0^{\frac{\delta}{2}}\cos^n(x)\geq \frac{\delta}{2}\cos^n(\frac{\delta}{2})$, I don't notice anywhere wrong

Comment: Sorry for my wrong comment! I'll delete it.